# Find a regional maximum with imregionalmax

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to find a regional maximum within my data.  I started with the function `imregionalmax` but I can't get the results I want.

I'm getting my data from a csv file and say a column have 5.2 ,5.6 and 5.3 surrounded by low values compared to these, `imregionalmax` labels all three of these values as 1 (since output is binary), but I want to select only 5.6.

Is there a way that I could scan the whole grid to check for all the neighbouring cells to each cell and compare it to them if it was bigger than the surroundings?

Comment: maybe use [blockproc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/blockproc.html?searchHighlight=blockproc) qith the `max` function?

Comment: If your input has 5.2, 5.6, 5.3 in a connected  row, surrounded by lower values, then `imregionalmax` should only select the 5.6.  It would help if you showed how you were reading in your data and running it through `imregionalmax`.